# what's the purpose of double question mark in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have seen such function:

```
public func highlightValues(highs: [ChartHighlight]?)
{
    // set the indices to highlight
    _indicesToHightlight = highs ?? [ChartHighlight]();

    // redraw the chart
    setNeedsDisplay();
}
```

What's the purpose of `??` here? I searched, but it seems searching `??` is hard to find a proper answer.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

It is called nil coalescing operator. If `highs` is not `nil` than it is unwrapped and the value returned. If it is nil then `[ChartHighlight]()` returned. It is a way to give a default value when an optional is `nil`.

Comment: The nil-coalescing operator a ?? b is a shortcut for

a != nil ? a! : b

Comment: This is very handy. In Javascript, you can use OR operator to achieve the same, like so: var thisIsNeverNull = thisStringMightBeNull || ""

Comment: Its good to give guarantee to a object will not be nil with using ??. Thanks for answer.

Comment: For clarity: If `a = false`, `a ?? b` will return `false`.